# Usage of で in the following sentence

Tags: meaning, particles

In "Minna no nihongo II" book, lesson 47, mondai question 6.3 there is a sentence:

> オーストラリアで山火事があったそうです.

Why is で used and not に? If both can be used what would be the difference between them ? would the meaning of the sentence change

Comment: @akj
 according to the post you sent me it should be ni and not de. However in minna no nihongo book this sentence is written with de thats why am so confused.
Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can express where an event happens or takes place by using ''で''.  
You cannot use ''に'' in this context.

I'm giving examples below.

- 東京{とうきょう}**で**会議{かいぎ}があります。
- 空港{くうこう}**で**荷物{にもつ}の検査{けんさ}がある。
- 山火事{やまかじ}があったそうです。- どこ**で**ですか。- オーストラリア**で**です。or どこ**で**（あった）かはわかりません。
- この町{まち}**で**は、11月{がつ}に大{おお}きなお祭{まつ}りがある。- となりの町**で**も（大きなお祭りが）ありますか。- となりの町**で**は（大きなお祭りは）ありません。

Meanwhile, you can use ''に'' to express where a thing is.

- 東京{とうきょう}**に**国技館{こくぎかん}(Sumo wrestling amphitheater)があります。
- 空港{くうこう}**に**荷物{にもつ}の検査場{けんさじょう}がある
- ウルルという巨大{きょだい}な岩{いわ}があるそうです。- どこ**に**ですか。- オーストラリア**に**です。or どこ**に**（ある）かはわかりません。
- この町{まち}**に**は、大{おお}きなダム(dam)がある。- となりの町**に**も（大きなダムが）ありますか。- となりの町**に**は（大きなダムは）ありません。